# Swing JButton: Icons and text in one position

Tags: java, swing, position, jbutton

Is it possible to use JButton I can put the text is right in the icon, not above, below, left and right side of the icon. If possible how?
[image: example]

Comment: Sure. Write the text **on** the icon before using it in the button. It will complicate rendering or keyboard shortcuts, though.

Comment: Maybe this posting will give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188213/jbutton-settext-specific-position/22189447#22189447

Comment: Thank you so much all. I've found the way, we have to set **verticalTextPosition** to **CENTER** and **horizontalTextPosition** to **CENTER**